# Dialog box minimizes on clicking elsewhere in the main window

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm using

```
dialog.showMessageBox([browserWindow, ]options[, callback])
```

to confirm a delete operation.I expect the user to close the dialog box first in order to perform some other operations.However, when the dialog box pops up the user is still able to click other parts of the window and on doing so the dialog box minimizes automatically.

Is there a way to restrict a user not to do anything else unless the dialog box is closed ?

Note: On Atom Editor do the following:
     File -> Open File , this results in a dialog box for opening a file and while this dialog box is opened, the user is not able to click on anything on the main screen. This is the same behavior I'm looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this feature that was recently added: https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/6140

Comment: Is this implementation applicable with dialog in windows platform ?

Comment: It says there under "Platform notices": On Windows it is not supported to change parent window dynamically. So I'm guessing that's the only limitation.

Comment: Thnaks  !! dialog.showMessageBox(Browserwindow,{}) seems to work.